# How to prove this equation with Bessel function in summation

Tags: bessel-functions

How to prove this:

$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{J_{2n}(z)}{n}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left\{\frac{(-1)^m(\frac{z}{2})^{2m}}{(m!)^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}\right\}$$

This equation occurs in converting standard BesselY function to Neumann's representation.

You can find this problem in the book 'A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions' by G. N. Watson, 1944, page 67. 
[screenshot of page 67](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udvze.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: (+1) Nice identity, some non-trivial manipulations are involved.

Comment: But the $(m)!$ in the RHS should be squared.

Comment: @JackD'AurizioThank  you very much for the remark. I have correct the equation. I am reading your answer now. There is some part iI don't understand that much how you do it. I will ask you later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well-known that
$$ J_{2n}(z)=\sum_{l\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^l z^{2l+2n}}{2^{2l+2n}l!(2n+l)!} \tag{1}$$
and that $J_n(z)$ has a very fast decay to zero as $n\to +\infty$ for a fixed $z$. It follows that:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}J_{2n}(z) &=& \sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{l\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{l+n}(z/2)^{2l+2n}}{nl!(2n+l)!}\\&=&\sum_{h\geq 1}(-1)^h (z/2)^{2h}\sum_{l=0}^{h-1}\frac{1}{(2h-l)!l!(h-l)}\end{eqnarray*}\tag{2} $$
and it is enough to find a closed form for the very last sum:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{l=0}^{h-1}\frac{1}{(2h-l)!l!(h-l)} &=& \sum_{l=1}^{h}\frac{1}{l(h-l)!(h+l)!}\\&=&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{h!^2}}\sum_{l=1}^{h}\binom{h}{l}\frac{ h!(l-1)!}{(h+l)!}\end{eqnarray*} \tag{3}$$
Here comes the magic of [Euler's Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{l=1}^{h}\binom{h}{l}\frac{\Gamma(h+1)\,\Gamma(l)}{\Gamma(h+l+1)}&=&\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{l=1}^{h}\binom{h}{l}z^{l-1}(1-z)^h\,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1+z)^h-1}{z}(1-z)^h\,dz\tag{4}\end{eqnarray*}$$
leading to:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{l=1}^{h}\binom{h}{l}\frac{ h!(l-1)!}{(h+l)!} &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-z^2)^h-1}{z}\,dz -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-z)^h-1}{z}\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-z)^h-1}{z}\,dz-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-z)^h-1}{z}\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-z^h}{1-z}\,dz = \color{red}{\frac{H_h}{2}}\tag{5}\end{eqnarray*} $$
and finally to:

> $$ \color{red}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}J_{2n}(z) = \sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^h (z/2)^{2h}}{\color{blue}{h!^2}}\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^{h}\frac{1}{k}}.\tag{6}$$

Comment: In the equation 2, how could you make the upper limit of the inner summation to 'h-1'? how is the term '$(z/2)^{2l}$' disappeared?. In the equation 5, how is the formula derivated? Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @YingTang: in $(2)$ at some point I perform the substitution $l\to h-l$ bringing the old summation indices ($1..h$) into the new ones ($0..h-1$). After $(2)$, I care just about the coefficient of $z^{2h}$.

Comment: In $(5)$ an integral is simplified through the substitution $z\to\sqrt{z}$, then another substitution is performed, $z\to (1-z)$. Everything pretty standard.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think the substitution $l=> h-l$ is done in step 3. The problem I don't understand is one step earlier.

Comment: @YingTang: oh, sorry, you are right. In $(2)$ I used $h=n+l$ as a new summation index. So $h$ ranges from $1$ to infinity and $l\leq h-1$ since $n\geq 1$.